# Using post method along with jquery modal window

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, servlets

I am developing an application using jquery ui and servlets.I have used modal dialog window for login.Once I Login the credentials are being sent to LoginServlet where the crendentials are checked and the user is being redirected to new page.

now Login.jsp has:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
  </script>
  </head>
 <body style="font-size: 62.5%;">
 <div id="dialog" title="DBoperations">
 <form id="LoginForm" method="post" action="Login">
 <fieldset>
 <label>Username:</label>
 <input type="text" id="username" value=""></input><br></br>
 <label>Password:</label>  
 <input type="password" id="password" value=""></input><br></br>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Log In" align="middle"></input>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Now when I run the application the data passed to the servlet is null.I checked it using println statements.As far as I know al it takes to pass data to servlet is specifying action and using getparameter on server side...

I am gettin Null pointer exception due to the null value being passed to the login method..

why are null values passed??

Comment: I don't see any code besides the `dialog` call.  what is sending the request; am I missing something?

Comment: @pixelbobby-wont the action tag "post" specify that the data should be sent through post method to servlet?? if this is wrong then how do I do it? Is it possible to use only post method and not the jquery

Comment: You have a typo in your code methinks.  A missing `}` between the script tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a name attribute to your inputs and see if that works. I believe the browser only sends the request parameter if it has a name attribute.

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="">
```